# Как оставить скроллбар стандартным, но при этом изменить его ширину?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

При добавлении ширины скроллбару он пропадает. Как изменить его ширину, но оставить стандартным?

Comment: Не мучайте бедный дефолтный скроллбар, используйте кастомный.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант, для всех WebKit браузеров:

```css
body {height: 300vh;}

::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 50px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: lightgray;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: gray;}
```

Однако, любое обучение всегда лучше начинать с учебников, например: [Пользовательские скроллбары в WebKit](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/polzovatelskie-skrollbary-v-webkit)